# How to disable the close (X) button on Google Chrome tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, browser-tabs

Is there any way to make Chrome not display an X button for each tab?

I have two reasons for this:

1. When I have many tabs open, the X buttons take a lot of screen real estate and make the tab titles shorter.
2. Sometimes I try to move to a different tab and accidentally close it because I push the X button by mistake. (Again, dense tabs.)

Since I almost always use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to close tabs, I don't really need the close button.

Is there any way to make it go away?

Comment: Frigging unbelievable that Google won't implement a pref to get rid of those cretinous X buttons on every tab, especially considering the importance they seem to ascribe to tabbed browsing.  This causes a lot of accidental closing of tabs for me, and makes me more likely to use Firefox for my everyday browsing.

Comment: Exactly the same situation here, except that I use `Ctrl+F4` to close a tab...

Comment: middle mouse button will close tab too ;)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T will re-open any closed tab.
I use that a lot.

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/704779/how-to-enable-confirmation-alert-before-closing-chrome-tabs

Answer (score 8):

at least I can not see the 'x' when i opened 20 tabs, except for active tab... but that said: no, there is no way of hiding the 'x' except grabbing chromium and changing the source code yourself.

Comment: Below a certain threshold the X button does disappear, but that threshold is too low for me.

Comment: Are you intimately familiar with the Chromium project and sure that there is no way?

Comment: I'm going to agree with Akira here.  I am not intimately familar with Chromium Project, but I have used Chrome since it came out.  It and Firefox don't allow you to remove the close tab button (x).

Comment: Firefox does, since 2006. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.tabs.closeButtons

Answer (score 4):

You can alternatively use the Vivaldi browser. It is also based on Chromium just like Chrome. It contains all the features that Chrome does plus a lot more.

Vivaldi includes a setting that removes the cross button from the tabs, it also has a built-in Notes system (so you can keep making personal notes while surfing), and all Chrome extensions work with Vivaldi. Most of all they have a great community that actually listen to your feedback.

I switched from Chrome to Vivaldi and never looked back.

Comment: Gonna try Vivaldi! But man where do devs take these awful names from for their software!

Answer (score 4):

Google, in their infinite wisdom, removed this option a while ago. Google seems to have started to move the way of Apple: lock everything down, make the UI as simple as possible, remove every option and customization possible, gain complete control over the user experience and the users themselves. Everything I loved about Google just 5 years ago has been thrown out the window.

I have spent many hours searching for a solution to this over many months and have yet to find anything that actually works. As an alternative, maybe try Vivaldi. It is a new Chrome/Chromium based browser that aims to bring back the old customizations and features that use to make made browsers great. It started out kind of shitty, but over the last year they have improved the UI and ironed out a lot of the bugs.

Comment: You did not answer OP question please edit your answer to provide a solution to OP

Comment: I added a potential solution i had offered in the comments to the main post.

Comment: New solution: Use Firefox. It's better now! No really, the new FF 57 "Quantum" is like Firefox used to be, but blindingly FAST when compared to anything else out there. Edge is the only other browser that comes close and it's....not ideal :|

Answer (score 3):

A possible work around is to add the extension Sexy Undo Tabs so, when you do commit a natural and human error which happens all too often for me, it's easy to recover from. Until the Chromium developers see the light and allow what at least 170 folks want (according to the summarily closed [Bug Request which you can star to increase the head count of folks asking for it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50913)), it may be your least worst option.

Comment: I doubt that more stars would catch their attention. I believe I've even seen an issue with a 1000 stars and still being ignored. I use my Google Photos app on Android and ever since I toggled a setting, it doesn't upload photos unless manually triggered. When it comes to fixing bugs, Google devs can be as blind as a bat. However, another option for your solution would be to use the cntrl+Shit+T hotkey in Chrome that will undo a closed tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Pin Tab` can fit your need.When right clicking a tab,choose `Pin Tab`, the close button has been disappeared and you can close the tab via Ctrl+W.

I do not know whether there is a plugin to remove the close button or not.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that if you select the left most tab and the press and hold shift and left click the right most tab and then right click and select "pin tabs" it will pin ALL the tabs and remove the "X" from them all :D you can do the same and select "unpin tabs" to reverse this, or just use CTRL+W to close the tabs you