# How to hide or remove the close button on tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling X buttons for Chrome tabs](https://superuser.com/questions/199384/disabling-x-buttons-for-chrome-tabs)

Every tab in Google Chrome has its own close (X) button. I click them by mistake when switching tabs and I am fine with using Ctrl-W to close tabs. So, they are useless to me.

Is there a way to hide or remove the close button on tabs in Google Chrome?